# Android onChange event not triggered in contentObserver for chrome history on android 5 (Lollipop)

Tags: android, google-chrome, history, android-5.0-lollipop, contentobserver

I've noticed that my contentObservers for chrome history and bookmarks do not trigger anymore on android lolipop. The code works perfectly on older versions of android (regardless of the chrome version) but on Lollipop it is not working anymore.

I've filed a bug on chromium and this is confirmed by others in the comments.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?q=obogzch%40gmail.com&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=435541&thanks=435541&ts=1416575883

Did anybody found a solution to this?

LE:
Thanks Fuong Lee for the workaround, call this method after you add the content observer to jump start it:

```
private boolean checkContentProvider(Uri uri) //uri = content://com.android.chrome.browser/history

   {
        Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        return (mCur.getCount() > 0);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I change new URI for chrome bookmarks from "content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks" to new URI "content://com.android.chrome.browser/history", the same issue "onChange event not triggered on Lolipop version". And, I try query data to check after observer registered... it running like a magic. I don't know why it running correctly, hope it help.

Comment: I can confirm this. Thanks for the answer!
Call this method after you add the observer and it triggers:
`private boolean checkContentProvider(Uri uri)

    {
  // String[] proj = new String[] { Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL };
  Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
  return (mCur.getCount() > 0);
 }
`